missing wallet on phantom app
I sold my memes coin and converted it to binanace, and it worked. However, the second memes coin I converted to binanace did not function for almost four hours. I checked with Solscan, and it showed success, but the money I took out kept dropping from $196 to $140. 
Anyone know what's going on? It's my first day.
